# Android Studio 3.6 RC3 Gradle infinite loop

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.6

So Since Android Studio 3.6 RC3 every time I perform a Build or a Gradle project sync it keeps repeating these four steps on an infinite loop. Does anyone know if this a bug or the project could have some configurations wrong? I tried the usuals, invalidate caches, restart, remove the project and download it again...

What shows in the process of being in an infinite loop:

```
Grade: DownLoad maven-metadata-.xml
Grade: DownLoad core-3.0.3.pom
Grade: DownLoad java-common-1.14.pom...
Grade: Build model...
```

I am only able to pass this behavior it by selecting the offline mode afterward.